# Merge one JSON and JSON array on the basis of JSON's value and JSON Array's key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I wanna try to create one JSON array in node by combine these two JSON and JSON arrays

```
`var template = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value3",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
};
var data = [
  {
    "value1": "1",
    "value2": "2",
    "value3": "3"
  },
  {
    "value1": "11",
    "value2": "12",
    "value3": "13"
  },
  {
    "value1": "21",
    "value2": "22",
    "value3": "23"
  }
];`
```

I need Resulted JSON be like

```
var result = [
  {
    "key1": "1",
    "key3": "3",
    "key4": "3",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
  },
  {
    "key1": "11",
    "key3": "13",
    "key4": "13",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
  },
  {
    "key1": "21",
    "key3": "23",
    "key4": "23",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
  }
]
```

In my case there will be around 40 keys in JSON array and around 25 keys in template JSON, So I'm also looking for Optimized solution for this. Anybody can help me in this?

Comment: Where are the data inside the `data` array ? Why is there `key1 : 1, key3 : 3, key4 :3` everywhere ? You just want to replace every data with the template ?

Comment: you sure. i think you want result like var result = [
  {
    "key1": "1",
    "key3": "3",
    "key4": "3",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
  },
  {
    "key1": "11",
    "key3": "13",
    "key4": "13",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
  },
  {
    "key1": "21",
    "key3": "23",
    "key4": "23",
    "key6": "Dummy Value1"
  }
]?

Comment: Sorry,Yes ashish you are right.. i need to update my result JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

```
// iterate over the array
var res = data.map(function(o) {
  // get the property names array and iterate to generate 
  // result object
  return Object.keys(template).reduce(function(obj, k) {
    // define property based on the array element object has 
    // the prefered property or not
    obj[k] = o.hasOwnProperty(template[k]) ? o[template[k]] : template[k];
    // return the object reference
    return obj;
    // set initial value as an empty object which is used as
    // the new array element 
  }, {});
});
```

```js
var template = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value3",
  "key6": "Dummy Value1"
};
var data = [{
  "value1": "1",
  "value2": "2",
  "value3": "3"
}, {
  "value1": "11",
  "value2": "12",
  "value3": "13"
}, {
  "value1": "21",
  "value2": "22",
  "value3": "23"
}];

var res = data.map(function(o) {
  return Object.keys(template).reduce(function(obj, k) {
    obj[k] = o.hasOwnProperty(template[k]) ? o[template[k]] : template[k];
    return obj;
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav C Balan :)

Comment: @MayankJain :  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the given data array and the keys and map the result for a new array.

```js
var template = { "key1": "value1", "key3": "value3", "key4": "value3", "key6": "Dummy Value1" },
    data = [{ "value1": "1", "value2": "2", "value3": "3" }, { "value1": "11", "value2": "12", "value3": "13" }, { "value1": "21", "value2": "22", "value3": "23" }],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        this.forEach(function (k) {
            o[k] = template[k] in a ? a[template[k]] : template[k];
        })
        return o;
    }, Object.keys(template));
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var template = { "key1": "value1", "key3": "value3", "key4": "value3", "key6": "Dummy Value1" },
    data = [{ "value1": "1", "value2": "2", "value3": "3" }, { "value1": "11", "value2": "12", "value3": "13" }, { "value1": "21", "value2": "22", "value3": "23" }],
    keys = Object.keys(template),
    result = data.map(a =>
        keys.reduce((o, k) => (t => Object.assign(o, { [k]: t in a ? a[t] : t }))(template[k]), {}));
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do this.

```js
var template = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value3",
  "key6": "Dummy Value1"
};
var data = [{
  "value1": "1",
  "value2": "2",
  "value3": "3"
}, {
  "value1": "11",
  "value2": "12",
  "value3": "13"
}, {
  "value1": "21",
  "value2": "22",
  "value3": "23"
}];

result = data.map(function(i){
  var o = {};
  for (var key in template){
    o[key] = template[key] in i ? i[template[key]] : template[key];
    }
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
``
```